# Double version of perl

Tags: perl

I had 5.13 perl version in my post .By mistake, I installed an other version (5.16).

If I uninstall the 5.16 version and keep just the old version, Is there any impact would be appeared in the old version's dll or packages ?

Comment: The answer depends a lot on *how* you installed another version of perl.

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple versions of Perl installed without problem, as long as they're installed in separate directories.

If you installed the new one in the same directory as the old one, you got a mess on your hand, and uninstalling the newer version won't magically bring back the older version.

If you installed the new one in the different directory than the old one, you can use either one, and uninstalling the new one won't affect the old one.

You may want to adjust your path and/or your file associations, but that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Perl versions with an odd number in the second position (e.g. 13) are development versions. The stable ones have an even number there (e.g. 14). You'll probably want to keep 5.16 (although we're up to 5.28 now, so you are quite behind).

Compiled libraries aren't guaranteed to be binary-compatible between these versions. If you compiled something against 5.13, that result may not work with 5.16. That's not a huge problem though; re-install the module for the new perl.